# $\{L(v_1),...,L(v_2)\}$ is a basis for $V_2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that if a linear map $L: V_1 \to V_2$ is an isomorphism and ${v_1,...,v_n}$ is a basis for $V_1$ then $\{L(v_1),...,L(v_2)\}$ is a basis for $V_2$. Explain why this shows that the dimension of $V_1$ equal the dimension of $V_2$

Can anyone explain this to me, got a finals tomorrow, thanks.

Comment: You need to show that $\{ L(v_1), \ldots, L(v_n) \}$ is linearly independant and every vector in $V_2$ can be written as a linear combination of $\{ L(v_1), \ldots, L(v_n) \}$. This can be done using the isomorphism property of $L$. If you have done this, you know that $\{L(v_1), \ldots, L(v_n)\}$ is a basis of $V_2$. Since the dimension of a vector space is defined as the number of elements in a bases, we have $$\dim(V_1) = |\{v_1, \ldots, v_n \}| = n = |\{L(v_1), \ldots, L(v_n)\}| = \dim(V_2) \; .$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the question about the dimension, see my comment above.

To proof that $\{L(v_1), \ldots, L(v_n)\}$ is a basis, you can do something like this:

Let $w \in V_2$ be an arbitrary vector in $V_2$. Define $v := L^{-1}(w)$. Since $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n \}$ is a basis of $V_1$, we can write 
$$ v = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i v_i \; .$$
By applying $L$ to this equation, we get 
$$ w = L(v) = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i L(v_i) \; ,$$
so every vector in $V_2$ can be written as a linear combination of vectors in $\{ L(v_1), \ldots, L(v_n)\}$.

It remains to show that $\{ L(v_1), \ldots, L(v_n) \}$ is linearly independant. Consider the equation 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i L(v_i) = 0 \; .$$
By applying the inverse $L^{-1}$ to this equation, we get 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i v_i = L^{-1}(0) = 0 \; , $$
and since $\{ v_1, \ldots, v_n \}$ is lineary independant, we must have 
$$ \alpha_1 = \cdots \alpha_n = 0 \; ,$$
so $\{ L(v_1), \ldots, L(v_n) \}$ is a basis of $V_2$.

Comment: thank you very much, your idea makes perfect sense man, thanks.